# Trying to Implement SSO b/n 2012 R2 ADFS external to internal 2016 ADFS(OpenID Connect Application)

Tags: adfs4.0

Subject: Trust external ADFS WS-Fed SAML claim to internal ADFS OpenID Application Group

1. Client has web-portal setup as a relying party to ADFS 2012 with WS-Fed SAML Claim
2. We have a applications with OpenID enabled in an ADFS 2019 Application Group
3. Client wants our applications to trust their web-portal sign-on when accessing our application
4. We setup the client ADFS 2012 as a Claims Provider Trust in our ADFS 2019

This is not working , we are unable get the claims from ADFS 2012.

Comment: So you log in to 2012 ADFS server via the Home Realm Discovery screen? What is not working as expected?

Comment: Subject: Trust external ADFS WS-Fed SAML claim to internal ADFS OpenID Application Group

Client has web-portal setup as a relying party to ADFS 2012 with WS-Fed SAML Claim.
We have a applications with OpenID enabled in an ADFS 2019 Application Group.
Client wants our applications to trust their web-portal sign-on when accessing our application.
We setup the client ADFS 2012 as a Claims Provider Trust in our ADFS 2019.

This is not working , we are unable get the claims from ADFS 2012.